# How do I get data from Realtime Database on React Native without an .on() event?

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am using the [React Native Firebase](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/) from Invertase, specifically the [Realtime Database package](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/database).

I can successfully retrieve data via a `reference.on()` [event](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/database/reference/reference#on) but am unsure how to retrieve the existing data; before a `.on()` event has been triggered.

I've gone over the docs a few times and even seem to figure out if this is even possible.

*Any* help or signposting would be helpful.

Here's some existing code:

```
// Create reference
const ref = database().ref(path);

// On reference change
ref.on('value', this.onRefChange);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on()` is, itself, the database query. So is `once()`. You use those to fetch data - it does not come any earlier than the results of those functions.